# how to hide inherited dialog properties on AEM

Tags: inheritance, adobe, aem, sling

I'm working on AEM 6.4 and I need to hide properties inside a inherited tab in a  node.

I have used "sling:hideProperties" but did not work.

I have seen that "sling:hideChildren" works but only with the first property
like : 
`sling:hideChildren="[property1, property2, property3]"`

Do you know if this feature has been removed?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to hide few properties of a node (Link Items) in List component (image below).

[image]

Have added the property `"sling:hideProperties String[] fieldDescription, text"` in the linkitems node (image below).

[image]

The  field properties fieldDescription and text has been hidden (image below).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Net Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11537508/net-solutions), the `sling:hideProperties` property *should* be working for you.

Just one important point: `sling:hideChildren` hides ***child nodes*** and not ***node properties***, so be careful about that.

If you still can't make it work, could you post the XML of your node tree in question?

Answer (score 0):

Since it was inherited dialog properties I ended up replicating the structure until I got to the properties I wanted to hide and used `sling:hideResource` and worked good. the rest of the inherited properties still show properly.

Regards.